# After ng update, ng serve and ng build getting ended without any result or error

Tags: node.js, angular

I was working on an old angular 10 project and I did "ng update" on it, After that "ng serve" and "ng build" getting ended without any result or error. I tried all possible solutions but still, have the same issue.

Here is what's happening
[image]

Things that I have tried

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
rm -r -fo node_modules
npm cache verify  
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm i
```

My Angular CLI

[image]

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "epsv2-cm-angular",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
 "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
 "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
 "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
 "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
 "moment": "^2.29.1",
 "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "^0.1.4",
 "ngx-mask": "^11.1.4",
 "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
 "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
 "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
 "tslib": "^2.0.0",
 "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.1",
  "@angular/cli": "^13.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~5.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~4.0.2"
 }
}
```

Comment: have you tried ng build --verbose, can give you more information what is going wrong

Comment: @vaira no, let try it out.

Comment: small reminder:-  Angular does not recommend/support migrating across multiple major versions at once. Please migrate each major version individually. https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-13.0